# Why am I getting an information not available, no symbols loaded d3d11.dll Error

Tags: c++, directx-11

I am new to the rendering API and I have been doing okay until now. I have been debugging a while to figure this one out and I just can't figure out why this isn't working. So I need some help.

I believe the source of the problem is here.

```
m_VertexShader->Release();
```

Because it doesn't return a HRESULT there isn't much I can't do.

Here is the code.

```
    #include "shader.h"

    ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram(Renderer& renderer, const char* vertShader, const char* pixShader)
    : m_Renderer(renderer), m_VertexShaderSource(vertShader), m_PixelShaderSource(pixShader)
    {
    Load();
    }

    ShaderProgram::~ShaderProgram()
    {
    m_VertexShader->Release();
    m_PixelShader->Release();
    m_InputLayout->Release();
    }

    void ShaderProgram::Load()
    {
    vector<char> vertSource = FileReader::read_file(m_VertexShaderSource);
    vector<char> fragSource = FileReader::read_file(m_PixelShaderSource);

    auto resultVert = m_Renderer.getDevice()->CreateVertexShader(vertSource.data(), vertSource.size(), nullptr, &m_VertexShader);
    auto resultFrag = m_Renderer.getDevice()->CreatePixelShader(fragSource.data(), fragSource.size(), nullptr, &m_PixelShader);

    if (resultVert != S_OK || resultFrag != S_OK)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Failed to create shader!", "Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[]{
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
    };

    auto result = m_Renderer.getDevice()->CreateInputLayout(layout, 2, vertSource.data(), vertSource.size(), &m_InputLayout);
    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Could not create the input layout!", "Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
```

Here is my rendering class. BTW I have just added stencil and depth testing just now and that could have to do something with the problem.

```
    #include "renderer.h"

    Renderer::Renderer(Window& window)
    {
    createDevice(window);
    createRenderTarget();
    createDepthStencil();
    }

    Renderer::~Renderer()
    {
    m_SwapChain->Release();
    m_Device->Release();
    m_DeviceContex->Release();
    m_RenderTargetView->Release();
    m_DepthStencilView->Release();
    }

    void Renderer::createDevice(Window& window)
    {
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChain = { 0 };
    swapChain.BufferCount = 1;
    swapChain.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChain.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChain.OutputWindow = window.getHandle();
    swapChain.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChain.Windowed = true;

    auto result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, 0, nullptr,
        0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChain, &m_SwapChain, &m_Device, nullptr, &m_DeviceContex);

    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Problem with creating DX11!", "Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
}

    void Renderer::createDepthStencil()
    {
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

    depthStencilDesc.Width = m_BackBuffer.Width;
    depthStencilDesc.Height = m_BackBuffer.Height;
    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, nullptr, &m_DepthStencilBuffer);
    m_Device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_DepthStencilBuffer, nullptr, &m_DepthStencilView);
    m_DepthStencilBuffer->Release();
}

    void Renderer::createRenderTarget()
    {
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer;
    auto result = m_SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&backBuffer);
    if (result != S_OK)
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, "Failed to get the swap chain buffer!", "Error", MB_OK);
        exit(0);
    }
    m_Device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, nullptr, &m_RenderTargetView);

    backBuffer->GetDesc(&m_BackBuffer);
    backBuffer->Release();
   }

    void Renderer::beginFrame()
    {
    m_DeviceContex->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RenderTargetView, m_DepthStencilView);

    auto viewport = CD3D11_VIEWPORT(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) m_BackBuffer.Width, (float) m_BackBuffer.Height);
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    m_DeviceContex->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    float clearColor[] = { 0.25f, 0.75f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
    m_DeviceContex->ClearRenderTargetView(m_RenderTargetView, clearColor);
    m_DeviceContex->ClearDepthStencilView(m_DepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);
    }

//Swaps the buffer!

    void Renderer::endFrame()   
    {
       m_SwapChain->Present(1, 0);
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you by chance, trying to debug in release mode?

Comment: ``resultVert != S_OK`` is not robust. Use ``FAILED(resultVert)`` instead. You have a number of functions here which return HRESULT values you are ignoring (``CreateTexture2D``, ``CreateDepthStencilView``, ``CreateRenderTargetView``, etc.). You need to check them all for failure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error when you run it in non-debug mode? With the limited info you've given it looks like your debug symbol table is not being found. If its all fine and dandy in non-debug mode then its off to sift through the docs to find out how to load the symbol table. Not much of an answer but hope it might help a little

Answer (score 0):

You really should move to using `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`. With raw pointers, you are likely to call `Release` too few or too many times, which is what happened here. See [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr).

It would remove silly things like the fact that you keep a dangling pointer to `m_DepthStencilView` even after you release it. You don't need to make it a member variable at all since you only use it to create m_DepthStencilView.

```
#include <wrl/client.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;
```

...

```
ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> depthStencil;
m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, nullptr, &depthStencil);
m_Device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencil.Get(), nullptr, &m_DepthStencilView);
```

> Take a look at the Direct3D 11 Game Visual Studio templates, in particular the implementation of [DeviceResources.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.h) / [DeviceResources.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp).